# 80% on heroku dynos what does this actually mean?

Tags: web, heroku, free, heroku-cli

Hello so right now I have 2 apps on heroku, 1 website, and a discord bot. Recently I just received an email about how I used 80% of my free dynos for "September 2021". So what happens if i reach 100%? and does the free dynos reset each month? can someone please explain thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you reach 100% the Dynos will be **shut down** (set to sleep) for the rest of the month.

At the beginning of the month the usage is **set to zer**o and you can start again with the full quota of the Free Tier.